# 64 Bit ELF Data Segment

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have a question about the following code provided by an OBJDump. I realize that the .data segment in a binary indicates statically defined data, however this following code does not appear as expected.

```
0000000000600348 <.data>:
  600348:   48                      rex.W
  600349:   65                      gs
  60034a:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  60034b:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  60034c:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  60034d:   20 57 6f                and    %dl,0x6f(%rdi)
  600350:   72 6c                   jb     0x6003be
  600352:   64 21 0a                and    %ecx,%fs:(%rdx)
```

What I originally wrote was something along the lines of

```
SEGMENT .data
  msg: dw "Hello World!",0xa,0x0
  msg_len: equ msg-$
```

Is this the same data just portrayed in a different fashion?

Comment: Yes. Take an ASCII chart and see. This nonsense code is what happens when you disassemble text.

Comment: @harold You know I have been working at this for about 2 hours now trying to decipher this and never once realized it was corresponding to the hex values.........

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this 
    "readelf -x .data ./binary"
or
    "objdump -s -j .data ./binary"
This will output it as you want it.
Hope this helps